# Properly append elements in for loop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, for-loop, append

Assuming that `cache["s"].length = 9`, and `cache["n"]` is an element in the DOM tree,

```
cache[ "c" ] = $("<div/>");
for( n = cache["s"].length; n >= 0; n-- ){cache["n"].append(cache["c"]); }
```

seems not working, and I have no clue, why.
It appends the div element ONCE instead of 9 times.

However, if I say,

```
cache[ "c" ] = "<div/>";
for( n = cache["s"].length; n >= 0; n-- ){cache["n"].append(cache["c"]); }
```

it works, I get 9 elements, but they are not properly inserted into the DOM tree.

What is the problem, how could I solve it without losing speed?

Comment: Do you mean `cache[n]`, no quote?

Comment: Nope, "n" is the index in the cache array.

Comment: Ok, the var name are not very intuitive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache["c"]` is a single element, which mean that when you append it over and over, it doesnt create a new `div` but take the old one and move it. Use `.clone()`:

```
cache["n"].append(cache["c"].clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 cache[ "c" ] = $("<div/>");
```

Here `cache[ "c" ]` is a instance of div element and if you try to apend it more than one time it replaces its instance.

But if use `cache[ "c" ] = "<div/>";` then it is appending new div element each time.

If you want to use  `cache[ "c" ] = $("<div/>");` then try appending its clone everytime.